# Drywall to metal building

Tags: drywall, insulation, metal, building

I have a metal building that I would like to ac and drywall. The walls are of course metal and double depth tube.

My concern is about moisture and dead load to the wall. My original idea is to use spray foam but that has tripled in price. From when I began this project so it is no longer an option.

What is the best application of foam board or batten with a vapor barrier?
Do I need to build a stud wall inside of the building or can I place insulation behind the drywall. then the drywall to the metal tube frame?

This is a Central Florida building

Comment: The metal studs would be a massive thermal bridge compared to even wooden studs, this could create issue in colder weather with condensation

Comment: For those of us not familiar with steel building construction, what is "double depth tube"?

Comment: You're asking several distinct questions here. Please see [ask] and revise to ask just one per post--either about insulation and moisture or about structure and drywall weight. Make sure your question is _specific_. "What is the best..." usually isn't specific enough here, and "Do I need to..." depends on the manufacturer's specs in this case.

Comment: "What is best..." invites opinion because your idea of "best" may not line up with mine. Define what you're looking to maximize (or minimize) and we can answer "best".

Comment: Keeping air away from the inside metal is critical especially in a high humidity area I would reconsider spray foam it really insulates better than anything when thinking of metal, my riding arena used to have fiberglass that did not work well (had to be removed) and that was from natural condensation from people and horses, I wish I had paid more for the foam , now on cold mornings it rains inside, that’s what caused the fiberglass to fail, any moisture in the air and a cold metal skin really condenses the moisture. It work well for a while.

Comment: What Ed is saying is that the "best" option is also the most expensive. It often (but not always) works that way in life...

Comment: when I say double depth means when you have a metal building the size of say a two car garage.  It is made with a single tube depth about 4 inchs.  This is a larger building that has two of them welded together.  So the wall space will be about 9 inchs deep. I hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the instances I've seen of this, you typically have (from outside to in)

1. Metal siding
2. Insulation with *plastic* vapor barrier
3. Metal framing

From there, most people select to stud frame next to the metal wall (building around the metal framing) and then drywall. Since that's all that you're doing, you can use normal kraft paper-faced 16" rolls to insulate. Remember that insulation *boards* don't provide as much R-value as their fiberglass batting cousins.

Can you attach the drywall to the metal? The largest problem is it would not allow you to do things like run electrical and plumbing very easily (running NM cable through metal frame is more complex than running it through studs). Depending how the members run, you might the vertical reinforcement of studs anyways. I've never seen a metal frame building with drywall on the outside wall framing.

Comment: So if I add a vapor barrier to the inside of the metal wall(exterior).  Then fiber glass or rock wool.  The drywall(high moisture) shouldn't get wet, or as wet?

Comment: I've not seen a building built like that do so... so, no.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  What would be the draw back??

Comment: The largest problem with attaching the drywall directly to the building frame is you won't have great support for the drywall. That's why virtually all opt to frame and then drywall the frame. Since outside the frame won't be conditioned space, it won't be an issue